# "{Profile.name}".includes ("*****") not working on the JS button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have an on-click javascript button on the list views. This button is used to perform Mass Actions on the records displayed in the list view.

We initially wanted this feature available only to Sys Admins. But Now we want to extend this button to 9 different profiles.

So instead of adding OR condition 9 times to the below code, I thought of using Contains or Include Function as all the 9 profiles I want to add CONTAINS MaxGen.

```
if('{!User.Profile}' == 'System Administrator')
So I modified this condition as below:
if('{!User.Profile}' == 'System Administrator'|| "{Profile.name}".includes ("MaxGen")). 

Now when i run the button by logging in as a MaxGen profile user, I'm seeing my alert message.

JS Code: 

    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js")} 
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/38.0/apex.js")} 

    if('{'{!User.Profile}' == 'System Administrator' || "{Profile.name}".includes ("MaxGen")'){ 
    var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.sm1e__smWork_Order__c)}; 
    var RecordIds = ''; 
      if(records[0] == null){ 
         alert('Please select a record'); 
      }else{ 
          for(var n = 0; n < records.length; n++){ 
             if(RecordIds == '') 
               RecordIds = '\'' + records[n] + '\''; 
             else 
               RecordIds = RecordIds+ ", " + '\'' + records[n] + '\''; 
          } 
           //alert('RecordIds: '+RecordIds); 
       try{ 
         var caseRecords = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, OwnerId, sm1e__Status__c, sm1e__Planner__c FROM sm1e__smWork_Order__c Where Id IN ("+RecordIds+")"); 

        var workOrderRecords = caseRecords.getArray("records"); 
            //alert('records: '+workOrderRecords); 
          for(i = 0; i < caseRecords.getArray("records").length; i++){ 
             caseRecords.getArray("records")[i].OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}"; 
             caseRecords.getArray("records")[i].sm1e__Status__c = "In Planning"; 

             caseRecords.getArray("records")[i].sm1e__Planner__c = "{!$User.Id}"; 
          } 
        sforce.connection.update(caseRecords.getArray("records")); 
        window.top.location.reload(); 
     }catch(e){ 
      alert('An Error has Occurred. Error:' + e); 
     } 
    } 
   }else{ 
        alert('You do not have necessary permissions. Please contact your system 
     adminstrator'); 
     }
```

How Can i Use CONTAINS OR INCLUDE on on to my Condition??

Comment: why not create a custom setting and use that in js button to see if the array of values contain your userprofile? this way you will be able to add edit profiles without touching the button code eg: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009477IAA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `{!$Profile.Name}`, not `{Profile.Name}`. Merge fields always start with `{!` and end with `}`. Accessing a user's profile is always done through `$Profile`. You should read about [Global Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables.htm) for more information.

Still, you should consider using a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=0). This allows you to add new profiles or even assign the permission to a specific user using a custom setting. It would simplify your code to just:

```
if({!$Permission.MaxGenMassAction}) {
```

Comment: can you write up a blog post or comment here on how you keep up with all these features :O. I try to read the releaase notes but I can never catch up as much as you do. How do you get to know about these awesome features, beyond the fact that you are jon skeet of salesforce.